# Error 'variable lengths differ' while doing Hoslem.test() in R

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

I am trying to do a hoslem.test() and ROC curve but I am struggling with a constant error. I am obtaining this error:

> `Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(y0 = 1 - y, y1 = y) ~ cutyhat) :  variable lengths differ (found for 'cutyhat')`

Firstly, I tried to see if the lengths from `montevil$icPM10` and `nrow(montevil)` were the same. They are (8790). After that, I tried to omit NA values from the logistic regression model. Nothing happened. I saw other websites, and people answered by coding the `na.omit()` clause in the model.

This is my code:

```
montevil<-read.csv("Montevil.csv")

#Hoslem.test
icPM10<-as.factor(montevil$icPM10)
b <- glm(formula=icPM10 ~ RS_re+vv+PRB+month, data = montevil, family = "binomial"(link=logit))
#install.packages("ResourceSelection")
library(ResourceSelection)
hoslem.test(icPM10, fitted(b), g=10)

#ROC curve
#This 'prob' variable was calculated in order to get the ROC curve
log.df <- data.frame(vv=0.6, RS_re="normal_alta", PRB=1013, month="08")
prob<-predict( b, newdata = log.df,type="response" )

#install.packages("pROC")
library(pROC)
r=roc(icPM10,prob, data=montevil)
## Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
## Setting direction: controls < cases
#plot (r)
```

Here is a link to the csv:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ap0Y-QMizgjKf1IB7mm_woJzEGEhlKPl/view?usp=sharing

### EDIT

I could figure out (I am not sure if this is OK) that I had to input this for the `hoslem.test()`:

`hoslem.test(b$y, fitted(b), g=10)`

But I am still struggling with the ROC Curve.